# Getting synonyms for a word based on context

Tags: word-embeddings

I want to get synonyms for a word based on it's use in sentence. for example in the sentence `I will book the hotel`, `book` is synonymous with `reserve` but this is not the case in the sentence `i was reading a book` one way is to check POS of the word in a given sentence but this is not always useful as multiple meanings of a word can share the same POS.

The problem of returning both antonyms and synonyms in word embedding would be solved by checking against a list of verified synonyms for the word.